# Why do two code snippets with identical assignment statements, exhibit different behaviors?

Tags: c#, .net

I know one is class and the other is struct, but why?

```
    private string? p1;
    public string P1 => p1 ?? (p1 = "");

    private int? p2;
    public int P2 => p2 ?? (p2 = 1);
```

[image]

Comment: Because the first is a nullable reference type (in this case `string?`) and the other is a nullable `int` value type which is represented by the generic type `Nullable<int>`. These do NOT behave the same way.

Comment: You would have to write the second one as: `public int P2 => p2 ?? (p2 = 1).Value;`

Comment: Just add `.Value`

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references for details.

Comment: Compiler says "*can not implicitly convert `int?` to `int`*". Which is not a problem for `string?` to `string` (as `string` is nullable too)

Comment: @Rafalon, the reason is that `int?` is a type different from `int` (`int?` is just C# sugar for the type `Nullable<int>`). `string?` however is not a type that is different from `string`. `string?` is actually the `string` type (the `?` here is only an annotation for code analysis instead of being part of a type name). You can assign a `string?`-typed value to a `string` var. and vice versa, because both are of the type `string`. But you can't assign an `int?` value to an `int` var. because `int?` is the `Nullable<int>` type and not `int` and there is no implicit conversion from int? to int.

Answer (score 1):

They are both poorly written IMHO. You are taking advantage of the fact that the result of an assignment is the assigned value, but in the second case, the value assigned is a *nullable* `int` (`Nullable<Int>`), not an `int`, so you need to explicitly get the `Value` from it to use it as the return value of a non-nullable property.

If it were me, I would either make the public property nullable, or make it non-nullable with an initializer (it's not clear why the backing field is nullable if you return a "default" value):

```
public int p2 = 1;
```